# sendmail: how can I restrict access to clients that only have a valid certificate?

Tags: linux, sendmail, certificate, slackware

I want to reject all connections that don't present a valid SSL/TLS certificate. 
First of all is the access db file the correct one to be changing?

I have already tried using the basic rule given in the documentation

> CertIssuer:/C=US/ST=California/O=endmail.org/OU=private/CN=
>   Darth+20Mail+20+28Cert+29/Email=darth+2Bcert@endmail.org  RELAY

This will obviously need a rule afterward to filter and reject all that don't present the cert? Does anyone have any pointers as to what syntax I should use? wildcards?

lxg

Answer (score 0):

Think I figured it out.. good old O'Reilly..

I just need to use:

```
TLS_Clt:                           VERIFY
TLS_Srv:                           VERIFY
```

Hopefully that will exclude all non valid certificates and all non secure connection attempts.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4823

> Note that it is unwise to force all SMTP clients to use TLS, as it is
>   not yet widespread. The RFC document notes that publicly referenced
>   SMTP servers, such as the MX servers for a domain, must not refuse
>   non-TLS connections. However, restricted access SMTP servers, such as
>   those for a corporate intranet, can use TLS as an access control
>   mechanism.

If you remove PLAIN from sendmail.mc, that should do it:

```
TRUST_AUTH_MECH('EXTERNAL DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
define('confAUTH_MECHANISMS', 'EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
```

then rebuild sendmail.cf with m4.